# Dynamic SQL query across multiple databases on the same server on same tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamicquery

Looking for a way to run the below code on multiple databases (20+ on my server that all have the same table schema). I tried using the `EXEC sp_MsForEachDb` procedure but not sure how to do this with multiple tables. My code is below, if anyone can help out with running this code on all database except temp and master i'd greatly appreciate the assistance.

```
USE PLX1

SELECT
    'X1' Company, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1), 112) PeriodEnd, 
    SUM(balfwd + debits - credits) Balance, 
    glcodes.Gl_Code + glcodes.[DESC] AccountName
FROM
    plx1.dbo.glsmry 
INNER JOIN
    plx1.dbo.glcodes ON glsmry.GL_CODE = glcodes.GL_CODE
WHERE 
    (glcodes.[type] = 'A1')
    AND glsmry.PERIOD_ID LIKE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) +1, -1), 112)
GROUP BY
    glcodes.GL_CODE, glcodes.[desc]
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

```
-- put all @DBNames in to a table ( or query from the schema tables)

declare  @DBName varchar(max) = ''


-- Write a Cursor and assign the valuues to @DBName

Declare @dynamicSQL varchar(max) =
'select ''X1'' Company, convert(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) +1, -1),112) PeriodEnd, 
SUM(balfwd + debits - credits) Balance, glcodes.Gl_Code + glcodes.[DESC] AccountName
from ' +  
@DBName + '.dbo.glsmry 
inner join ' +  
@DBName + '.dbo.glcodes on glsmry.GL_CODE = glcodes.GL_CODE
where (glcodes.[type] = ''A1'')
and glsmry.PERIOD_ID like convert(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) +1, -1),112)
group by glcodes.GL_CODE, glcodes.[desc]'

Exec (@dynamicSQL)
```

Or try the following (I didn't test this - so may need to tweak in case it troubles)

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDb '
if ''[?]'' not in (''[master]'', ''[model]'',''[msdb]'',''[tempdb]'')
Begin
select ''X1'' Company, convert(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) +1, -1),112) PeriodEnd, 
    SUM(balfwd + debits - credits) Balance, glcodes.Gl_Code + glcodes.[DESC] AccountName
    from [?].dbo.glsmry 
    inner join [?].dbo.glcodes on glsmry.GL_CODE = glcodes.GL_CODE
    where (glcodes.[type] = ''A1'')
    and glsmry.PERIOD_ID like convert(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) +1, -1),112)
    group by glcodes.GL_CODE, glcodes.[desc]
End
'
```